# Where does Asp.Net UserAuthentication store users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I was checking up to create a login system, now I found this standard login from Visual Studio. [this link Authentication Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth) I chose Individual User Accounts.

Now I'm curious to know where the data is saved.

I made a registration to the program afterwards I closed the app, hosted it again on my localhost and I still could log in with the same account.

I debugged the code, but it refers to the dll: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 
I checked my local database but there are no users. 
Removed the local database, still able to log in or register

Answer (score 2):

Check your app data folder. You might have a DB automatically there. If not, Click View->Server Explorer. You might see something useful there.

Comment: Oh, now I see that you have answered yourself. Well, it might help someone else, so I won't delete it if that is ok :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the connectionString in de webconfig file!
I managed to change the string to my own database and the program does the rest!